# Jquery link reloads page

Tags: jquery

I´m working on this webpage:

http://sociedadmicologicasegoviana.com/

When  "Inicia sesión" topbar button is clicked, an hidden div appears, but when you want to close with the image, it reloads the page. Does anyone know why?

The following code is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="login">

<div class="row" id="login-dialog-close">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="" id="login-dialog-button-close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row login-div">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <?php echo do_shortcode("[swpm_login_form]"); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("#login").hide();

$("#login-button").click(function(){
    $("#login").show(500);
});

$("#login-dialog-button-close").click(function(){
    $("#login").hide(500);
});
```

});

I´m unable to understand this behaviour cause it´s not a button, just a span..

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span is inside an anchor element, with the `href` attribute set to `""` - this refers to the current site, and will effectively reload the page when clicked.

You should really avoid using anchors when not actually linking to another web page. Instead, you should change it to a `div` (you can style it to show the pointer with `cursor: pointer;`).

However, if you *really* want to use the anchor, you could change the `href` attribute like so:

And then make sure your javascript returns false:

```
$("#login-dialog-button-close").click(function(){
    $("#login").hide(500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `#login-dialog-button-close` is a link, clicking on it follows the link. You can prevent this in a few ways:

- Change `href=""` to `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`.
- Call `event.preventDefault()` in the handler.

  ```
  $("#login-dialog-button-close").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#login").hide(500);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<a href="" id="login-dialog-button-close">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

With this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login-dialog-button-close">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

the problem is because the link's `href` attribute is empty.  Using `javascript: void(0);` or `#` in `href` will resolve the issue.